# How to extract parameter names from SQL query

Tags: c#

I have a SQL query

```
select * from table where field1 = :param1 and field2 = :param2
```

I want to get the parameter names from this string.
For example: `[param1, param2]`

How to do this using c# language?

Comment: This seems pretty simple, let me make sure i fully understand. You would like to extract the parameter names from the string, correct?

Comment: @TraeMoore OP said `I want to get the parameter names from this string`. Does that not clarify it already?

Comment: yes, all words with prefix `:` or `@` or `?`, for exampe...

Comment: What have you tried? Regex should work just fine.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, expected output and what specifically isn't working. This can be handled numerous ways, we need to see what you are currently working with to provide a detailed answer and feedback.

Comment: @GBWDev, You missed the part where it didnt say exactly that...

Comment: @MattU so would `linq`, `substring`, `replace`; we don't know what the OP is working with, why would `regex` be your choice in this case?

Comment: It was just a suggestion.

Comment: I tried with indexOf (':'), but couldn't quite dissolve to return me an array with all parameters

Comment: @MattU I know :) I was just asking why `regex` in this case?

Comment: No particular reason. :P That's just the first one that came to my mind, without much thought. The ones you mentioned are obviously feasible. Not necessarily a right/wrong here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's one of the ways to solve the problem.

**Regex Info** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8

**Code :**

```
public static void Main()
{
    string rqx = @"([:@])\w+"; // or only one @"([:])\w+"
    string sql = "select * from table where field1 = :param1 
                                        And field2 = :param2 
                                        And field3 = :param3
                                        And field4 = @param4";
    Match[] matches = Regex.Matches(sql, rqx)
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .ToArray();


    foreach(var p in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
:param1
:param2
:param3
@param4
```

Comment: This solution is inefficient to many steps involved. Also this would return the symbol along with the name for example: `@param1`; didn't the OP say, `I want to get the parameter names from this string. For example: [param1, param2]`; according to this, the symbols are not included.

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes how does this work perfectly, it doesn't meet your request according to your post? @@Anu Viswan answer is more appropriate; it supports your rule and is efficient.

Comment: It may not have been clear, but it need not necessarily be `:` and `@` in the same string. That's why it also fits.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I think the main problem is to find the parameters 
and my answer solves the problem. 
The result is not very important because the example says it is not the rule. 
and added a note at the beginning of my answer
"I think that's one of the ways to solve the problem."

Answer (score 5):

You could use Regex for the purpose. For example,

```
[:?@](?<Parameter>[\S]+)
```

Above regular expression would help in retrieving the parameter names. The expression translates to a word that starts with either of (:?@) followed by a non-whitespace word (\S).

Complete Code

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[:?@](?<Parameter>[\S]+)");
var str = "select * from table where field1 = @param1 and field2 = :param2";
var matchCollection = regex.Matches(str);
var result = matchCollection.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["Parameter"].Value);
```

Comment: no explanation, we don't know what the OP has tried etc... Have you read the comments?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ ...aarh...hadn't read the comments...sorry, should i delete ?

Comment: An answer is an answer, but this IMHO is opinionated as the OP hasn't provided any code for us to help them.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I totally agree with you. I should have waited for OP's attempted code. It was my mistake

Comment: This Regex works correctly on select statements, however if you test it on Update Statement, commas are returned with parameter names